# Setting up WebServer with my domain name

Tags: server, configure

I just bought my domain name from godaddy. I would like to use my ubuntu server that I've set up. Where do I start on setting and configuring my ubuntu web server? Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of reading ahead of you my friend.  The short answer to your question is to install and configure Apache which is arguably the best web server software around.  It's been the standard that hosts the lion's share of web sites worldwide.  Fully answering your question would require a lot of typing so I'll just get you started.

Install apache by entering the command

sudo apt install apache2

Apache actually requires very little work and configuring to operate "out of the box".  However it is extremely rich in features and you could spend years really understanding all of it's ins and outs.  A good information starting point can be found at

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Once you get Apache operational you'll need to configure your Godaddy DNS to resolve to your server's IP address.  Your web server will need to have a fixed IP.  There are (complicated) ways around this but for simplicity do not try to run a web server that is connected via DHCP or that has a non-routable IP address.

I presume you are doing this as a learning exercise.  It's actually a lot easier and costs very little to have your web site hosted by an ISP.  About $10 USD per month.

Comment: Cool thanks. I've been reading into Apache for about a year now.  Fixed IP huh, I think I'm getting somewhere now. What you're telling me makes sense. Yeah you're right.  This as a learning excercise but I'm also doing it because I want my own server. I don't like that I'm addin all my coding and programming on godaddy servers. It's not like I'm working on secret breakthrough research. I do just like to keep my stuff private.